# Is the composition of a homeomorphism with itself orientation-preserving?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

Just a short question about the degree of a homeomorphism. So, I understand that in the
continuous setting we define the *degree* of a map $\ f: M \rightarrow M$ on a connected orientable manifold as the induced map on the top homology group (which is isomorphic to 
$\mathbb{Z}$).

If $\ f$ is a homeomorphism the degree can be either equal to $1$ or $-1$.

If the degree of a homeomorphism $f$ is equal to $1$ we call $\ f$ *orientation-preserving*.

Is it true that, since the degree respects the composition of maps, i.e. deg$(g \circ f) = $ deg($f$)deg($g$),

$f^2$ is always orientation-preserving for every homeomorphism $f:M \rightarrow M$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You already gave the proof.